# Limiting the user input in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, validation

I am working on an exercise where I need the user to input 25 values, all between 10 and 60.
I want to validate that these values are between 10 and 60.

```
void main()    
{   
    int len[25], i;    
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter length: ";
        do
        {    
            cin >> len[i];          
        } while (len[i] >= 10 && len[i] <=60);              
    }       
}
```

This is what I've got, but it would seem to me like the user isn't limited between 10 and 60. since when I input a value that's greater than 60 for example, and try and output it later, I see it is stored in len[i] regardless.
Any thoughts on how I would go about fixing this? Sorry, I'm a little bit of a noobie.

Thanks!

Comment: Your range check in the while(...) is wrong. Also, have a function reading a single value and look up how to detect and react on stream (input) failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's axactly what you do here

```
cin >> len[i];
```

You might go for

```
int n;
while(cin>>n)
{ 
 if(n<10 || n>60) {
  std::cerr << "value out of range" << std::endl;
  break; // ore may be continue ?
 }
 len[i]=n;
}
```